# Prevent / Hide drives from My Computer won't effect

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

I am planning to have a small internet cafe and want to prevent/hide them from opening Drive D which is for games. I enabled *Prevent access to drives from My Computer* and *Hide these specified drives in My Computer* on Local Group Policy Editor but I can still access the drive. Tried regedit, restarting pc, running gpupdate /force command but no to avail.

The user I want to restrict is an admin account. The one you create during Windows 10 installation. I want the admin account not to open the Drive D partition but still run the games within the said drive. Is it possible?

Need your advise.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think group policy is the way to do this.**

You need to restrict access via account privileges. Assuming you'll be granting access via guest accounts you can do the following:

### **Changing Folder Permissions**

> 1. Right Click on the Folder you wish to restrict properties on
> 2. Select “Properties”
> 3. In the Properties window go to the Security tab and click on Edit.
> 4. If the Guest user account is not on the list of users or groups that
>      have permissions defined, you should click on Add.
> 5. Now you need to type the user name or the group of users for which
>      you want to change the permissions. Type “Guest” in the names box.
> 6. After adding the guest account, Click Check Names and then click OK.
> 7. In the Security window, select the user/group you just added and
>      then click in the first check box under Deny which is “Full Control”
>      and then click OK.

Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-security/restricting-guest-accounts-access-to-my-files/a75b4c4c-c060-4bdc-80e2-66cd9e11ba8d

Comment: Before following the instructions above, the user I want to restrict is an admin account. The one you create during Windows 10 installation. I want the admin account not to open the Drive D partition but still run the games within the said drive. Is it possible? Thanks!